# syntax error, unexpected ' ' Laravel 5.6 ConsoleTvs chart js

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I have followed the requireiments for ConsoleTVs chartjs
upgraded to PHP7, laravel 5.4 to 5.6 
followed this documentation https://erik.cat/projects/charts

```
public function chart()
 {
  $chart = new SampleChart;
  // Additional logic depending on the chart approach
  return view('chart_view', ['chart' => $chart]);
 }
```

when I try to run it it says:
syntax error, unexpected ' '
been searching for days search previous documentation but not working, followed the new documentation still not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the command 
`composer update`
And make sure to dump $chart with `dd($chart);` juste to make sure it's working

Comment: already did, match the php -version PHP 7.2.8, in laravel composer, added other requirements

Comment: I think there's a problem with "Comments, white spaces" in the codes, I have cleared all the commented codes, white spaces. and it all just works fine, reverting the comments makes the error again

Answer (score -1):

try this codes Sir:

return view('chart_view', compact('chart'));

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as `return view('chart_view', ['chart' => $chart]);`.